# BigQuery invalid JSON

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I am trying to import a small JSON file on BigQuery but I am getting an error during the upload: `Invalid field name "5527453". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long. Table: popopo_5466c12e_eded_418b_b558_e6d53c8d0926_source`. What can be the issue? I checked the validity on my JSON and it's a valid JSON file.

```
{
    "5527453": {
        "conversion_events": {
            "data": [{
                "id": "111972323",
                "name": "Website Adds of Payment Info"
            }, {
                "id": "111971323",
                "name": "Website Adds to Cart"
            }, {
                "id": "11197132",
                "name": "Website Purchases"
            }, {
                "id": "1119727",
                "name": "Forfait + Fixe 4p"
            }, {
                "id": "111972517",
                "name": "Fixe"
            }, {
                "id": "111972",
                "name": "Total Fixe"
            }, {
                "id": "111972514",
                "name": "Total Forfait"
            }, {
                "id": "11197251",
                "name": "Forfait"
            }, {
                "id": "11197251",
                "name": "Device RM"
            }, {
                "id": "111972",
                "name": "Total Device"
            }, {
                "id": "11197251",
                "name": "Device nu"
            }, {
                "id": "1119725",
                "name": "Forfait + Device"
            }]
        },
        "id": "3184292"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Because your JSON will be loaded into BigQuery as a table, with "5527453" being the name of the column. BigQuery doesn't allow number-only column name, this is what the error message is complaining about. Here `field` just mean table column.